# The controller is not being updated

Tags: swift, xcode, controller, uitextfield

Such a problem: I write text in a TextField, for example, a ДОМИК , and when I go through the button (it did not get into the frame) to the main screen -> menu -> Add. Then this text is saved.

What I tried: 1 - do not save to coredata - the text remains anyway.
2-using print, I output a list where I store the textfield. The first time before entering it shows [] an empty array, and when I go through the controllers again to this screen, it shows nothing. As if the screen is not readable.

I need after each click on the menu-an updated controller, that is, an empty one, without a user-filled UITextField

[image]

```
func didSelect(menuItem: MenuViewController.MenuOptions) {
    toggleMenu { [weak self] in
        switch menuItem {
        case .home:
            self?.resetToHome()
        case .calendarPay:
            break
        case .statistics:
            break
        case .addProperty:
            self?.addProperty()
        case .settings:
            break
        }
    }
}


func addProperty() {
    let vc = addVC
    homeVC.addChild(vc)
    homeVC.view.addSubview(vc.view)
    vc.view.frame = view.frame
    vc.didMove(toParent: self)
    vc.delegate = homeVC
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adjusting the code：

```
func addProperty() {
    let vc = "you addVC".init()
    //...
}
```

Comment: !thanks for the answer! He helped! I asked everyone what and how, I reviewed everything on the Internet, no one knows anything! There is a question: tell me what this topic is called, I want to understand more about data transfer via init

Comment: Just create a new UIViewController every time, nothing special.@PollyVern

Comment: Wait, what? Calling init() on a static string? You mean `SomeViewController.init()`?

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, you need an empty textField every time you visit the textField's ViewController and to achieve the same you need to set textField's text value as empty. So when you visit or present the controller over screen the textField would be set to empty.

```
vc.textField.text = ""
```

Comment: if it was so easy, then I didn't ask for help. On the first visit to the controller, everything works as it should, and on the second visit, the controller is not updated